# How to generate click able table grid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to generate click able table grid using javascript.

My code is not working.

1. I created 2 text input fields for get values for row and column.
2. Button that will call `drawGrid()` function onClick event.

   ```
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="inputX"/>
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="inputY"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="drawGrid();"/>

     <script language="JavaScript">          
     function drawGrid(){             
        document.write('<table border="1">');              
           var x_start = 1;
           var x_end = document.getElementById('inputX').value;
           var y_start = 1;
           var y_end = document.getElementById('inputY').value;
           // loop over all x values (rows) sequentally
           for( var x=x_start; x <= x_end; x++ ){
               // open the current row
               document.write('<tr>');
               // loop over all y values (cols) sequentally
               for( var y=y_start; y <= y_end; y++ ){
                   // write out the current x/y coordinate with a table cell
                   document.write('<td> x:'+x+' y:'+y+'</td>');
               }
               // end the current row
               document.write('</tr>');                    
               document.write('</table>');
           }
    }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple of points I think are worth making:

1. document.write is not the best tool for this job.
2. (and far more serious) Have a look again at your nested for-loops. 
   You perform the outside loop width number of times. In this loop you create a new row, add some cells, close the row and then close the table.

Read #2 again - that's right, you try to make `width` number of rows instead of `height` number of rows. You also ***finish the table*** *each row* (yet only start the table once)

Here's some code that uses the ability to create elements with JS objects (a opposed to js-created text strings)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClicked, false);
}

function onCellClicked(evt)
{
    alert( this.innerHTML );
}

function onGoBtnClicked(evt)
{
    byId('tblTgt').innerHTML = '';
    var nCols = byId('inputX').value;
    var nRows = byId('inputY').value;

    var tbl, curRow, curCell;
    tbl = newEl('table');
    var x, y;
    for (y=0; y<nRows; y++)
    {
        curRow = newEl('tr');
        tbl.appendChild(curRow);

        for (x=0; x<nCols; x++)
        {
            curCell = newEl('td');
            curCell.addEventListener('click', onCellClicked, false);
            curCell.innerText = "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
            curRow.appendChild(curCell);
        }
    }
    byId('tblTgt').appendChild(tbl);
}

</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
    nCols:<input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="inputX"/><br>
    nRows:<input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="inputY"/><br>
    <button id='goBtn'>click</button>
    <hr>
    <div id='tblTgt'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you enhzflep.
Its working now. but cells are not clickable.

Comment: @user3119557 - you're welcome. Sorry, I overlooked that. I've added a new function `onCellClicked` and have attached this as the event listener for the `click` event on each cell. Because I've attached the function via JS instead of writing it inline in the HTML, the `this` parameter points to the element itself - this allows us to use just one function for any number of cells. :)

Comment: One more thing. how can we toggle the color of the clicked cell (white & black).
if black then it should be white and if white then it should be black.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure thing, I've updated the solution. Take note of (1) the css rule for elements with the class `active` and (2) the updated `onCellClicked` function. - Each element has a member `classList` - this allows you to do all kinds of manipulations on the list of classes that an element has, without resorting to string manipulation, like was once necessary.